# Trigger works only onClick but not when loaded without it

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I'm trying to figure out why my trigger works put in onClick but not outside it when script runs through.

I've got this function to select checkboxes from url: (`exampleURL/abc#filter+checkbox1+checkbox+checkbox3`). After refreshing page it should check those checkboxes and trigger "change".

```
    var hash = location.hash.slice(1).split('+');
    var hashLen = hash.length;
    for (var arrIndex = 1; arrIndex < hashLen; arrIndex++)
    {
        var hashLog = hash[arrIndex];
        $('input[type=checkbox][value="'+ hashLog +'"]').prop('checked',true);
    }
    $(".abc-filter-sidebar input[type=checkbox]").trigger("change");
```

Unfortunetely it doesn't trigger. But when i put trigger in click function it works:

```
$(".abc-filter-results").on("click", function(){
$(".abc-filter-sidebar input[type=checkbox]").trigger("change");});
```

I will be very grateful if someone will show me my mistake :)

Comment: You are probably not waiting for the DOM-ready. In jQuery this is done with using the $.ready function, as in `$(function { /* the inline code here, only run after the elements are created */ })`. Otherwise, check the error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it :)

It was pretty simple. I've used on("load") function:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
$(".ideas-filter-sidebar input[type=checkbox]").trigger("change");});
```